# how to redirect a sub domain to any url (Apache2 & Ubuntu)

Tags: ubuntu-one, apache2

I want to redirect my 'http://www.mysite.com' to 'http://www.newdomain.com/Login.html' on apache2.Please help me ,how to do that.I am not getting how to use RewriteCond & RewriteRule.Please help.

Answer (score 4):

Turn on Apache rewrite:

```
sudo a2enmod rewrite
```

Edit your Apache config file...

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.mysite.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.newdomain.com/Login.html [R=301,L]
```

301 = permanent redirection

Restart Apache.

Answer (score 0):

### The easy way

Create a file named `index.php` with the following contents: `<?php header('Location: http://www.newdomain.com/Login.html'); ?>`.
You don't need to use ModRewite if you find it too hard. ;)